# Performance star schema (BI)

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, oracle11g, business-intelligence

We have different meassures per company, country and product:

Company A, Australia, Beer, 10, 22, 3, 9

Common use case is to calculate the sum of measure 1 for beer in a specific country.

I have two options in mind:

**Option A:**

Dimension-Table:

```
ID
Company
Country
Product
```

Measure-Table:

```
Dimension.ID (FK)
DateTime
Measure1
Measure2
Measure3
Measure4
```

Or **Option B:**

All-In-One-Table:

```
ID
Company
Country
Product
DateTime
Measure1
Measure2
Measure3
Measure4
```

In the dimension-table are 10,000 unique records and in the Measure-table nearly 30,000,000 records.

At the moment we use alphanumeric key for product, company and country.

*My question*:

Which performs better?

Any suggestions for indexing the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that average size of one row in "dimension" table is 50 bytes (just guessing) and in the "measure table" also 50 bytes then in Option A you would have database of size not less than 1.5 GB, and in Option B not less than 3 GB. This is a significant difference.

So I would say that Option A is better because the database size is smaller.

Indexing depends on queries you want to use. But I think that when using Option A no indexes (apart from those created by primary and foreign keys) are needed because the "dimension" table is small.

Comment: Storage is cheap :) But we need the queries as fast as possible.

Comment: I did not even think about money ;). Only about performance and cluster size.

Comment: If the data uses more space, each time you access it, you have to read it. And reading twice as much data will hence take twice as much time. Furthermore, it decreases the chance that the data you need would be cached in memory, as only half as many records can be kept in the same amount of RAM. And accessing data in RAM is faster by a factor in the range of ten or maybe a few hundred.